# iPhone creating nested views

Tags: iphone, view, controllers

I'm noob in iPhone programming.

I want to create navigation-based application with several nested views, when first and second are UITableView-type, and the third is simple UIView with my own interface, which I built in Interface builder.

When I run the App, touch the row on the first table-view I transfer to the second, and when I touch the row on the second, I transfer to the third, but on the third View I don't see my interface, which I built in Interface Builder, just blank screen.

This is part of my code, where I try to call my third view:

```
    if(self.reportView == nil){    
        ReportTypeViewController *viewController = 
        [[ReportTypeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReportTypeViewController" 
                                            bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.reportView = viewController;
        [viewController release];        
    }


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.reportView  animated:YES];
    self.reportView.title = @"Reports";
```

---

That's OK, guys.
I've just didn't add text to my button, that lies on my view, that's why it was blank.

Comment: Is ReportTypeViewController a subclass of your 2nd UITableViewController (the one that calls it)?

Comment: It's inherited from UIViewController.

Comment: I created ReportTypeViewController by choosing UIViewController subclass. How to make sure, that ReportTypeViewController is a subclass of my 2nd UITableViewController?

Comment: After reading some more of your comments, I don't think this is your problem but you can try it and see. To make ReportTypeViewController a subclass of your 2nd UITableViewController, open the header (.h) file for ReportType view controller and replace "ReportTypeViewController : UIViewController" with "ReportTypeViewController : NameOfSecondTableViewController" again I'm pretty sure this isn't your problem... as far as I know a UIViewController should work.

Comment: An error shows, when I change the class I inherted from.

Comment: I even see my controls from IB in debug in viewController-variable, but when I run my app, this view is blank :(

Comment: That's OK, guys.
I've just didn't add text to my button, that lies on my view, that's why it was blank. 
;)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `[NSBundle mainBundle];`

it should look like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ReportViewController *vc = [[ReportViewController alloc] initWithNibName:ReportViewController bundle:nil];
    vc.title = @"Reports";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}
```

If you just create the view on demand with the selection it's much easier.

Comment: I made exactly what you wrote, but there's still the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In IB, make sure you remembered to set the Class of File's Owner to `ReportTypeViewController`, and make sure that the `view` outlet of File's Owner is connected to your view.

Comment: I checked your advices in IB, it's OK. But the app still works not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Does `ReportTypeViewController` really inherit from `UIViewController`, or is it a `UIView`, as you say you built in IB?

`navigationController pushViewContoller:animated:` needs a `UIViewController` not a `UIView`. In IB, you can add a `UIViewController` and move your `UIView` onto it, or create it programmatically.

Comment: Yes, it's inherited from UIViewController.